# Generating a new project in buffalo fails with GO111MODULE issue

Tags: go, project, buffalo

I am trying out buffalo for the first time.

I manually installed the pre-requisites rather than using scoop because I didn't know where scoop would put things:
https://www.stuartellis.name/articles/windows-golang-setup/#installing-buffalo

Installed buffalo using this from Powershell and it seemed to work OK:

```
go get -u -v github.com/gobuffalo/buffalo/buffalo
```

However when I went to generate a new project using this example:
https://gobuffalo.io/en/docs/getting-started/new-project/

```
buffalo new coke
```

I receive the following.

```
DEBU[2019-07-17T20:55:51+10:00] Exec: go mod init coke
go: modules disabled inside GOPATH/src by GO111MODULE=auto; see 'go help modules'
```

If anyone has any idea of what the problem is or how I can avoid it please let me know.

I don't know how to set GO111MODULE within Windows and I've googled this issue for the past 2 hours without success including searches on https://gobuffalo.io

I've tried reinstalling buffalo but this didn't help.

My GOPATH is E:\dev\go

Here is what I issued in order to create a new buffalo project (and I issued it from the correct folder within GOPATH E:\dev\go\src\github.com\):

```
buffalo new coke
```

Here is the result from issuing 'go env'.

```
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\canto\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=e:\dev\go
set GOPROXY=
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=e:\Go
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=e:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GCCGO=gccgo
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set GOMOD=
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\canto\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build677176826=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

I have successfully created a sample 'coke' buffalo project at work however it fails on my home workstation.

Comment: have you tried `setx GO111MODULE "on"`? this will set the environment variable to the shell you run, then running the `go get -u ...` should turn on Go Modules

Comment: Alternatively, if the project requires modules, just don't use GOPATH.

Comment: Anzel: setx GO111MODULE "on"
Thanks for that, now I get a problem with simply installing buffalo using 
"go get -u -v github.com/gobuffalo/buffalo/buffalo" the last message I receive is "go get: error loading module requirements", tried setting it off same issue. JimB: thanks but I don't really know what "don't use GOPATH" entails. Many thanks for trying but what I think I will do is grab a docker image instead

Answer (score 0):

Started again from scratch, manually uninstalled everything.

Following this:
https://www.stuartellis.name/articles/windows-golang-setup/

I just used scoop to create a default install of all the apps; I knew I wouldn't like the result because it put them all on my C:\users\ which is only for my OS

Then I ran `buffalo new coke` which failed with an error message along the lines of 'you need to be inside GOPATH'

Then I ran `buffalo info` which gave me all sorts of useful stuff, one of which told me that my PATH needed to match where I was running it from (which I thought was quite clever of it), then light dawned, my path was e:\dev\go and I was running it from E:\dev\go\src. Yes, a capitalization issue. Changed my path to 'E:\dev\go', reran `buffalo info` and only got warnings about things I wasn't interested in, ran `buffalo new coke` and it worked.

Now I'm uninstalling scoop and all my scooped apps, changing my custom path using SCOOP and SCOOP_GLOBAL and then re-installing scoop and all the apps again via scoop.

So, capitalization.

Answer (score 0):

```
GO111MODULE=on go get -u -v github.com/gobuffalo/buffalo/buffalo
```

https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules here's all you need to know how work with modules